# Can I delete the "createPartitionOutput" objects created by Athena in S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

After configuring Amazon Athena to use "s3://bucket" for its output, it has been writing objects to "s3://bucket/results", "s3://bucket/resources" and "s3://bucket/createPartitionOutput".

Over two years have passed, and now the objects in the latter prefix are consuming many terabytes. Can I delete them without issue, or are they necessary for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Every file which was created by Athena is simply a result of a query that you had executed. So if you don’t need those results then you can delete them without affecting any of your original data.